# boost program_options generating a Klocwork MLK.MUST

Tags: c++, boost

using a straightforward example, Klocwork insight detects:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
po::options_description oArgDesc("Options");
oArgDesc.add_options()
("sN", po::value<vector<string>>()->required()->multitoken(), "List of destination names.")
("sV", po::value<vector<string>>()->required()->multitoken(), "List of source names.")
;
```

Klocwork message:
Memory leak. Dynamic memory stored in 'po::value > ()' allocated through function 'value,std::allocator >,std::allocator,std::allocator > > > >' at line 27 is lost at line 26. Also there is one similar error on line 26.

Single-step inside: value_semantic.hpp, near line 185 (boost 1.54), I see new():

```
typed_value<T>* r = new typed_value<T>(v);
```

Looking inside: options_description.hpp, near line 70, I see an empty destructor

```
option_description::~option_description()
{
}
```

I do not see an obvious location where a delete is called, in the 
boost\boost_1_54_0\boost\program_options\detail*hpp files.

I have not tried another memory analysis tool (e.g., purify) as of yet either.

Answer (score 2):

The `value_semantic` eventually becomes managed by a `boost::shared_ptr`.  The `value_semantic` will leak if an exception is thrown in `new`, `boost::shared_ptr`'s constructor, or `boost::program_options::option_description`'s constructor.

With the following code:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
po::options_description desc("Options");
desc.add_options()
  ("name", po::value<std::string>(), ...) // add option
  ;
```

`boost::program_options::value()` will allocate a `value_semantic` in the free store.  When added as an option, the `value_semantic` is passed to a newly created `option_description`, managed by a `shared_ptr` within [`options_description_easy_init::operator()`](https://github.com/boostorg/program_options/blob/4a2094a1c36ead84a4836e9a0b39573edea2b2fb/src/options_description.cpp#L256).  Within `option_description`'s [constructor](https://github.com/boostorg/program_options/blob/4a2094a1c36ead84a4836e9a0b39573edea2b2fb/src/options_description.cpp#L64), the `value_semantic` becomes managed by a `shared_ptr` when it used to initialize the [`m_value_semantic`](https://github.com/boostorg/program_options/blob/4a2094a1c36ead84a4836e9a0b39573edea2b2fb/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp#L137) member variable.

Comment: What is the difference? What is your code suggest? you remove stc::vector and several function, but is that all?